# How to solve not-null property references a null or transient value error in oneToMany save method spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a spring boot project with two entities category and book.

Each category has one to many books.

Book entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_book")
public class Book {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id", nullable=false)
    private BookCategory category;

    //other fileds, getter and setter ...
```

Category entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_category")
public class BookCategory {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="category",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Book> book;
    
  //other fileds, getter and setter ...
}
```

BookRepository :

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>{
    @RestResource(path = "categoryid")
    Page<Book> findByCategoryId(@Param("id") Long id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

When I try to do post request:

`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/books/` with body {"name":programming}

I got this error :

```
not-null property references a null or transient value :
com.tarif.project.entity.Book.category; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException
```

Comment: You have set the `category` in `Book` to be `nullable=false` but you are not providing it in the payload. Try to remove the `nullable=false` and it should work. 
Of course if you want it to be not-null you have to provide it

Comment: Ok post works, but the category_id is not added in the database, even if i provide it in the payload like   : {"name":"test"",category_id":3}

Comment: In the response body I can not see category_id, but I can see other fields that have value null.

Comment: Hello artisans. What is the correct answer to this question?